# How to deform the attached object using rigged hand model?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I am working on a physics based Rigged hand model which detects collision when touches any object and then attaches to the object to be able to pick it up. This feature came as a part of the purchased package. Now, I added a Deforming script to the object to deform the vertices when a collision is detected. But, due to the AttachObject script, I guess the collision forces are ignored and the object does not get deformed.

How can I go about this issue? I am new to Unity.

```
void AttachObject(Rigidbody objectToAttach, FingerType holdingFinger1, FingerType holdingFinger2)
    {
        _lastForearmPosition = Parts.Forearm.transform.position;

        Parts.Fingers[(int) holdingFinger1].IsHoldingObject =   Parts.Fingers[(int)holdingFinger2].IsHoldingObject = true;
        AttachedObject = objectToAttach.gameObject.AddComponent<AttachedObject>();
        AttachedObject.Attach(this, DetachObject);
        Parts.IgnoreCollisions(objectToAttach, true);


        OnObjectAttached(objectToAttach);
    }
```

and Deformable script-

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        //Get point, impulse mag, and normal
        Vector3 pt = transform.InverseTransformPoint(collision.contacts[0].point);
        Vector3 nrm = transform.InverseTransformDirection(collision.contacts[0].normal);
        float imp = (collision.impulse.magnitude * 100);
        Vector3 collisionForce = collision.impulse / Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        if(false){
            Debug.Log ("evaluating if-false condition");
        }
        Debug.Log (collisionForce);
        if (imp < minImpulse)
            Debug.Log ("Force is less.");
            return;

        //Deform vertices
        verts = m.vertices;
        //Debug.Log (verts.Length);
        float scale; ///Declare outside of tight loop
        for (int i = 0; i < verts.Length; i++)
        {
            //Get deformation scale based on distance
            scale = Mathf.Clamp(radius - (pt - verts[i]).magnitude, 0, radius);
            Debug.Log (radius - (pt - verts[i]).magnitude);
            //Deform by impulse multiplied by scale and strength parameter
            verts[i] += nrm * imp * scale * malleability;
        }
```

I have tried using other scripts to deform the body, but each time the original Attach object script starts ignoring the collisions and my added script becomes useless.